# HTML links which don't "lose" url search part. How to?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

let's say I am on this page:

```
http://localhost:4444/index.html?user=test
```

my index.html page has a link like this:

```
<a href='help.html'>help</a>
```

If I click on it the browser takes me there and my url changes it to this:

```
http://localhost:4444/help.html
```

But what I wish it had happened is that I would **not lose the 'search query'** 
so that I would be taken here:

```
http://localhost:4444/help.html?user=test
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this ? 
possibly without javascript..

Comment: One algorithm can be to save a copy of the URL query in the cookies and whenever a new page is requested from the server, send a 301 message (permanently moved) to the new query string from cookie.

Comment: If you don't want to do it with JavaScript then you're going to have to do it with server-side code.  Plain HTML doesn't have anything for this.

Comment: @David Can you elaborate your answer ? are you sure plain html has nothing for this ?

Comment: @Zo72: Well, to my knowledge it doesn't.  But if you discover otherwise then by all means share it, I'd love to learn something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no easy solution for this problem.
You need to use javascript and the location object.

you need to ensure that you enrich the a urls with the search part

(and others e.g. hash if required)

Answer (score 1):

You can read also document.referrer from the visited page

```
//localhost:4444/index.html?user=test
```

and split on '?' to get the search expression.